# Why is it possible to eject my C drive as if it were a USB drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb

I just used a USB drive to move some files. Being the good, ethical computer user I am I ejected my drive prior to removing it. I do this this everytime. Though this time I was oddly presented with the option to eject my C drive as if it was a USB drive.

Why is this now, or ever, an option? What would happen if I chose this option? Is it possible to make this not an option in case I get click happy?

[image]

Comment: install a newer Intel AHCI driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a result of an SATA drive being treated as though it were eSATA.
You can ignore it as it has no detrimental effect in itself, though you can set the registry to treat the drive as a fixed internal drive if you wish.

1. Click Start
2. In the Search programs and files box, type command
3. In the Programs list, click Command Prompt and click Run as administrator
   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or click Continue.
4. Copy and paste or type each of the commands into the command prompt and press Enter after each command
   `reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\msahci\Controller0\Channel0" /f /v TreatAsInternalPort /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001`

   `reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\msahci\Controller0\Channel1" /f /v TreatAsInternalPort /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001`
5. Restart your computer to enable the registry changes

Note: There may be some trial and error to determine the correct ports (also referred to as "channels").
The channel numbers shown in Device Manager may not match the channel number in the registry, so you may need to set the value and verify the desired effect.

Source: [My internal SATA device appears in Devices and Printers and in the Safely Remove Hardware area of the system tray?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/my-internal-sata-device-appears-in-devices-and/722221d6-d59c-4cf7-803c-8203e6344b93)